# How to break up Jenkins Testing

Tags: maven, selenium, testing, jenkins, automated-tests

**Background**

I am currently in the process of writing test scripts in Java with Testng, Maven, selenium and Jenkins. I have a plan to write hundreds of scripts. At this current time I have about 80 scripts written. Only 8 scripts have been uploaded to Bitbucket. Note that each script can have anywhere between 5-25 tests in it based on complexity, for example the 8 scripts currently on the server run 100 tests.

**Problem**

The issue I can see arising here very very quickly is that a huge amount of test scripts running.Jenkins runs the entire Maven project that sits on Bitbucket. Currently with only 8 scripts Jenkins takes a total of 20 mins to run. By the time I have the more complex ones up this could take hours to run even days with all of the scripts I plan on uploading.

**Research**

So far I've looked around for some way to break up the testing process so for instance I would have separate Maven projects in my Bitbucket repository for different areas. Then I would have several different builds on Jenkins one for each area of the site. I'm not sure how that would work though since Jenkins seems to just go in and read all of the tests on my repo.

I'm almost certain that having all of the tests in a single  build is bad practice but I just cant find information on how to handle a huge test suit, I'm hoping someone with real experience can clarify this for me.

**Software**

Added as a side note in-case anyone wants to know what I'm using

- Maven: 3.3.3
- Java: 1.7.0_79
- Selenium: 2.46 & 2.47(currently 2.47)
- Jenkins: 1.622

**Conclusion**

I believe there must be a way of breaking the test suit up without having separate bit-bucket repos for each section.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is using selenium grid. This will allow you to distribute tests over several vm's. Its fairly well [documented](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2).

Comment: Thanks for the input but really I'm looking to create different builds from one bitbucket repo in jenkins.